unexpected `cfg` condition value: solana
I'm trying to make a smart contract with Solana and build it using Anchor on WSL, but everytime it always gives a target_os warning like this:
warning: unexpected cfg condition value: solana 
--> programs/vote-sc/src/lib.rs:5:1 
| 5 
| #[program] 
| ^^^^^^^^^^ 
| 
= note: expected values for target_os are: aix, android, cuda, dragonfly, emscripten, espidf, freebsd, fuchsia, haiku, hermit, horizon, hurd, illumos, ios, l4re, linux, macos, netbsd, none, nto, nuttx, openbsd, psp, psx, redox, rtems, solaris, solid_asp3, teeos, trusty, tvos, uefi, unknown, visionos, and vita and 6 more 
= note: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/check-cfg/cargo-specifics.html for more information about checking conditional configuration 
= note: this warning originates in the macro $crate::custom_panic_default which comes from the expansion of the attribute macro program (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

I've tried to reinstall everything but it didn't solve the problem. It also had other warnings but it seems that I could fix them by adding:
anchor-debug = [] 
custom-heap = [] 
custom-panic = []

into my Cargo.toml under [features]

You can't mark questions as duplicates between sites, but credit to this answer on Solana Stack Exchange which I will copy here:
RUSTUP_TOOLCHAIN="nightly-2024-11-19" anchor build

